Enclosing a unit cube in unit cubes
What is the smallest number of unit cubes that can enclose a unit cube so that even its edges and corners are completely covered?
If the cubes lie on the cubic grid, it is clear that 26 are needed.  However, without this restriction, 12 cubes suffice.
Has this problem been identified before?
A correspondent of mine has provisionally answered the corresponding problem for dicubes (1x1x2 blocks).  Her answer was 8, lower than I expected.
The central cube must have no "breathing space" around it.  The surrounding cubes must enclose it fully, including its corner points.
Below is a vertically exploded picture of the 12-cube solution.

When the layers are joined, the central cube lies within the interior
of the assembly.  None of its points lies on or beyond the solid's surface.
Some questions I would like to be able to answer about this problem:
1. Can 12 be proved to be the minimum for the problem with cubes?
2. Can 8 be proved to be the minimum for the corresponding problem with dicubes?
3. How does this extend to general polycubes or general polyhedra?
Here is a diagram showing that Joyce Michel's idea for enclosing a dicube in 8 dicubes is sound:

It relies on the fact that a domino can be contained in the interior of a shape formed by two dominoes. These kinds of geometric arrangements are not entirely obvious.

I'm not quite sure about the point of your question. I have not seen the problem before. So my answer would be "no". Are you trying to carry out an opinion poll or to find a reference?

I suppose that no two cubes may both occupy a region of non-zero volume. I also suppose all cubes are closed and that by "surround" you mean every point of the original cube has a neighborhood that is entirely covered by cubes. I don't see (yet) how to do it in 12 cubes.

@RobArthan I think you can cover all faces and eight edges that way, but the edges between the "other 4 faces" are not completely covered. It seems easy enough to do it with 14 cubes (in several different arrangements).

@DavidK: you are right. I was missing some edges.

To the OP: since your question has stimulated some interesting discussion. I think it would be good if you enlarged on the mathematical aspects so that it can be reopened.

I think I understand how to do it with 12 cubes now if they don't have to be axis-aligned.

It might be related to this MO problem.

@CalvinLin I think the questions are related, but the MO question seems a bit lacking in definition.

This is only a very partial answer, but comments don't support pictures as far as I know.
Here's a domino covered by two dominoes:

It's difficult to see the gaps between the inner domino and the edges of the covering dominoes, but you can zoom in on the relevant vertices here: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/sbwhzdky .
A construction might be: rotate the middle domino by an angle very slightly less than $\arcsin\frac2{\sqrt5} - \arcsin\frac1{\sqrt5}$, that is,
so that it fits between two horizontal lines $2$ units apart without touching them but is very close to touching both.
Align this domino with the lower domino so that it almost touches two edges of that domino with its vertices as shown in the picture.
Place the third domino symmetrically to cover the rest of the rotated domino.

I think the problem you're trying to solve is equivalent to this:
starting with a cube $C$ (faces, edges, and vertices included), find an open subset $C'$ that covers $C$ and its interior, then find $N$ other cubes congruent to $C$ such that the $N + 1$ cubes are non-overlapping and are a cover of $C'$;
find the minimum $N$ for which this is possible.
The problem for dicubes has a similar formulation.
